# How to handle static master data as models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to treat non-database master data, such as the ones in `config/master_data/something.yml`, as Rails models (like Active Record)?
I'd like to have functionalities such as fetching an item that matches a specified id as if it's a record or retrieving a list of names for all records. I anticipate accessing this data from various places, like controllers and views. Here's a sample of the yml data:

```yaml
items:
  - id: 1
    name: "Item1"
    description: "Description for Item1"
  - id: 2
    name: "Item2"
    description: "Description for Item2"
```

Comment: Why don‘t you write those data into the DB on deploy? when you have to return that data by ID anyway, having it in the DB is probably the easiest option.

Comment: I already have a file at `config/master_data/something.yml`. While there is a possibility to persist this data to a database in the future, I initially wanted to make use of the current static data.

Comment: This is what `rails db:seed` and the `db/seed.rb` file are great at keeping in sync on deploy, especially if you do a `find_or_create_by` on the values.

Answer (score 4):

In Rails ActiveModel is separated from ActiveRecord so it's trivial to use it as a mixin to create models with any data source (or no data source at all):

```
class Item
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :id,          :integer
  attribute :name,        :string
  attribute :description, :string
end
```

This gives you a model that behaves very much like ActiveRecord models when interacting with the rest of the framework.

You could then load the YAML data and create model instances that you store in [the respository pattern](https://dev.to/cherryramatis/simple-repository-pattern-for-ruby-on-rails-2lje).

```
class ItemRepository
  def initialize(file:)
    raw = YAML.load_file(file)
    @data = raw["items"].map do |hash|
      Item.new(hash)
    end
  end

  def find(id)
    @data.detect { |model| model.id == id }
  end
end
```

## However

There are huge cons to not having the data reside in the database:

- The data cannot be used in join queries from your other database backed models.
- You lose all the features that ActiveRecord associations give.
- You cannot use the data in foreign keys to ensure referential integity.
- Your data becomes hard coupled to the codebase. This adds a bunch of noise in the version history of the project and it now becomes a developer concern to modify the data instead of something that can for example be done by a DBA.
- The data very likely won't be as "static" as you initially thought. For example removing an item becomes very problematic when you don't have foreign keys telling you which database rows you'll orphan and you can't use cascades or callbacks to handle it.
- Databases are really freaking good at storing data and querying it efficiently. Your cobbled together solution? Not so much.
- Maintainers will hate you.

Whatever benefit you think using a file as data storage provides is definately not worth it IMHO. It would be better to just use the YAML data to seed your database.

Comment: I hope it's abuntantly clear that I don't think you should use the code in the first section. It's merely a proof of concept of a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mimic the behaviour with Plain Old Ruby Objects (PORO). You need to create a class that copies the behaviour of ActiveRecord.

So for example you can do something like this:

```
    class Item
      attr_accessor :id, :name, :description
    
      def initialize(attributes = {})
        @id = attributes['id']
        @name = attributes['name']
        @description = attributes['description']
      end
    
      def self.find(id)
        yml = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'master_data', 'something.yml'))
        data = yml['items'].find { |item| item['id'] == id }
        new(data) if data
      end
    end
```

I would not recommend loading the yml like this and rather have it somewhere in a constant. But you will get the idea on how to use POROs.

Afterwards you can access it like:

```
item = Item.find(1)
```

The question is why you do not want to store this data into the DB? It is easier to maintain and handle when you use the DB and ActiveRecord.

Comment: Not quite: `initialize` will be executed for instances. `@yml` in the class context (like in `self.find`) will be `nil`. You could introduce another class method `self.yml` which holds the data.

Comment: @Stefan yes, you are right. Depending on how he wants to initialise the yml data, there are different ways. Will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: While you could do this there really isn't any point in reinventing the wheel if what you want is something that behaves like a model. ActiveModel provides all those API's for you.

Comment: Not sure anyone actually calls them "PORO". That's a term from Java that's leaking in to Ruby, as in Java many objects tend to be wrapped up in layers of abstraction. In Ruby they're often plain-by-default.

Comment: @tadman while I don't generally use the term, hundreds of SO questions and more than 1MM results on google suggests that people very much use this acronym.

Comment: @engineersmnky It's Java lingo leaking into the Ruby world, and the same has happened to Python/PHP with "POPO", etc. Enterprise Java people are likely astonished by the fact you can just make an object by declaring it with `class`, that no further ceremony is required. No factories! No beans! In other words, *regular Ruby code*.